# Display trailing zero on conversion using round function in SQL Clickhouse query

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Whenever I use the round function, I get an integer value instead of a float.

For example when I run the below code

```
SELECT ROUND(12.99, 1)
```

I get 13 instead of 13.0.

What function can I try to get the answer I want?

Comment: you should get the *float* type - check it `SELECT ROUND(12.99, 1) as a, toTypeName(a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toDecimalString`...

*Converts a numeric value to String with the number of fractional digits in the output specified by the user.*

*Returned value: Value represented as String with given number of fractional digits (scale). The number is rounded up or down according to common arithmetics in case requested scale is smaller than original number's scale.*

```
select toDecimalString(12.99, 1)

Output: 13.0
```

As you noted, the `round` function will ignore the zero and display as integer.